# React router is stacking routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying again:

I'm using props.history.push('/something') from a route '/test'

but then I'm redirected to '/test/something' instead of '/something' how can I make it happen?

my example cant work with `<Route> <Redirect> <Route>` because I'm passing props with my router, for example '/something/:id' any ideas?

EDIT:

```
  <Route
            exact
            path="/search/:id"
            render={(props) => <SearchResults />}
          />
```

when I use onclick function like so:

```
const onSubmit = () => {
    props.history.push(`search/${id}`)
  }
```

I get pushed to search/search/:id instead of search/:id ( I have the search button always present in all my components) any ideas?

Comment: Can you create a reproducible demo please

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri hey check my edit

Comment: ```props.history.push(`/search/${id}`)
  }```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you do not add a prefix `/` to your `history.push` method, it redirects you to the route relative to the current route i.e if your current route `/search`, `props.history.push(`/search/${id}`)` will take you to `/search/search/:id`

Adding a prefix `/` will fix your issue. since it tells the history to add an absolute route

```
const onSubmit = () => {
    props.history.push(`/search/${id}`)
  }
```